# sort a selection of a pandas dataframe only (keep some columns fixed)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, selection

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = {'Brand': ['HH','TT','FF','AA'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
        'Year': [2015,2013,2018,2018],
        'Misc1': ['Description: ', '', '', ''],
        'Misc2': ['Car Prices 2022', '', '', '']        
        }
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Brand','Price','Year', 'Misc1', 'Misc2'])
print (df, '\n')

df.sort_values(by=['Brand'], inplace=True)
print(df, '\n')
```

I would like to keep Misc1 and Misc2 columns fixed

this does not work

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['Misc1', 'Misc2'])].sort_values(by=['Brand'], inplace=True)
print(df,'\n')
```

does anybody here know a good way to do this?

Comment: you mean, after sort description and car prices belongs to AA? Please add the desire outcome

Comment: yes in this case, but to be more specific in all cases it should be on the first row; in the two misc columns I want to put information that always should stay on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

breakup your DF into two DFs, while resetting the index on first one

```
df2=df[['Brand','Price','Year']].sort_values(by=['Brand'] ).reset_index()
df3=df[['Misc1','Misc2']]
```

join the two DFs

```
df2.join(df3).drop(columns='index')
```

```
    Brand   Price   Year    Misc1           Misc2
0   AA      35000   2018    Description:    Car Prices 2022
1   FF      27000   2018        
2   HH      22000   2015        
3   TT      25000   2013
```

here is the original DF, before sort

```
    Brand   Price   Year    Misc1           Misc2
0   HH      22000   2015    Description:    Car Prices 2022
1   TT      25000   2013        
2   FF      27000   2018        
3   AA      35000   2018
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can assign the `Misc` column back after sorting

```py
out = df.sort_values(by=['Brand'])
out[['Misc1', 'Misc2']] = df[['Misc1', 'Misc2']].values
```

```
print(out)

  Brand  Price  Year          Misc1            Misc2
3    AA  35000  2018  Description:   Car Prices 2022
2    FF  27000  2018
0    HH  22000  2015
1    TT  25000  2013
```

Comment: Thanks! this does the job too, I would add the following line df = out.reset_index(drop=True)