# Sort part datframe decreasing and an another part increasing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a data frame with 6 column a,b,c,d,e,f
i want to sort a,b,c by a (ascending) and d,e,f by f (descending)

Comment: Not really , because i dont want to sort one column ascending and one column descending . i want to sort several column together by one of them

Comment: I want to sort a,b,c by a and d,e,f by d

Comment: that's what @GonçaloPeres's answer does

Comment: There he says df.sort_values(['a', 'b'], ascending=[True, False]). its to sort a ascending and b descending . My problem is that the price , the quantity and the name are bound

Comment: You want to sort, so why not just do it instead of asking?

Comment: I dont understand. if i have a,b,c,d,e,f i want abc together and def together. I dont see this in the response of @GonçaloPeres

Comment: Can you help me to understand

Comment: It s not the same problem @Claudio

Comment: @Nathan, you specify the ascending attribute with True and False for the columns that you like to be in ascending and ones you like in Descending. the answer linked shows exactly that syntax. hope it helps

Comment: But price and qty are bound together . i dont want to specify wich column to sort in ascending or descending . i want to sort 3 column together by one of them and 3 together by one of them. How can i specify sort 3 column together

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593436/sort-a-selection-of-a-pandas-dataframe-only-keep-some-columns-fixed *( sort a selection of a pandas dataframe only (keep some columns fixed) )* answers your question.

Comment: @Nathan : by editing your question the right answer appears now strange and not directly related to your question, so your edit wasn't helpful or being an improvement. Consider to accept the answer and rollback to the version of the question addressed by the given answer. By the way: what you ask for are two independent data frames saved in one data frame - this does not make much sense in the context of your question and resulted therefore in listing a not appropriate duplicate link.

Comment: From the beginning my question was in this direction. you just didn't want to understand that the answer from the previous link was not the right one.

Comment: Maybe it was not clear enough but I understood that the answer I was offered did not correspond

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the easy way out but you could use this until someone point it out.

df_desc=self.orderbook_agreg_btc[["bids_qty","bids_price","exchange_name_bid"]].sort_values(["bids_price"],ascending= False)

df_asc=self.orderbook_agreg_btc[["asks_qty","asks_price","exchange_name_ask"]].sort_values(["asks_price"],ascending= True)

df = df_desc.append(df_asc)